# How can I find a three square panel door similar to this one?

Tags: doors

I've spent a while online trying to find a door like the one below that I could buy to replace it.  My search term has been 'three square panel carved door'.  Nothing even close.  And I can't find a manufacturer name anywhere on it.  Any suggestions?

[image: front door with carved panels]

Comment: Is that the only door like that in the property? Perhaps it was a special commission? An import from another country?

Comment: It may be helpful to concentrate your question more on the repair or replace aspect of this door. As it stands now this is positioned as a "shopping question" and is liable to be closed.

Comment: Certain basic door designs are standard (6 panel door, 12 light french doors, etc), but this is not one of them.  Finding a match would be pure luck and you'd probably only find one at a reclaimed building supply thrift store.

Comment: **Why ?**, Perhaps we can help with an issue with your door. ??